# PHP log when session expires

Tags: php, session

I am trying to diagnose a session related issue, and I am trying to find a way to write to a log file when a session expires. I am hoping I can tail a log file on my mac and see the session expire. Specifically we have a session dying before 120 minutes and trying to determine why and when.

My first thought was to put into a session an object with a destructor and put a log statement in the function. I haven't tried this but since the object is serialized I am thinking it's likely not going to call the desctructor.

I was looking into custom session handler functions and was hoping maybe I could overload the destroy, but since GC is picking up the expired that might not help even though it may not be possible.

Obviously if I setup a call to check the session value are there that will extend the session. so yeah not sure if there is a way to handle this.

So I am looking for ideas or possible solutions on how to log when a session expires or is destroyed. If you have any other ideas how I might accomplish this let me know.

Comment: You'd have to roll your own session handlers. PHP's default session garbage collector doesn't log its operations and is essentially invisible in the background. It doesn't even log that it ran at all, so there's no way to tell if anything happened except by looking at the session storage location and watching for removals.

Comment: Deleted/expired sessions are also not loaded/unserialized. it's pretty much just a "scan directory for files unmodified longer than the expiry interval and remove them". Any data in the session files is just deleted without ever being looked at.